# Which is more effective at raising pH, Tums or baking soda?

Tags: acid-base, buffer

Chemical buffers like Tums (calcium carbonate) and bases like baking soda (sodium bicarbonate) are both used medically to reduce acidity in the stomach to ease heartburn symptoms. I'm curious which is more effective in vitro.

I'm interested specifically in the comparison in effectiveness of bases and buffers, which act in slightly different ways to raise pH. I'd also love to learn the math behind figuring this out so next time I can answer such a question myself :)

Comment: Useful terms to search are Henderson-Hasselbalch equations in buffers. Also note that Na and Ca are spectator ions, but they have different charges. Which one will be more effect in terms of mass for neutralizing 1 mol of HCl ?

Comment: @M.Farooq All else being equal, baking soda has a molar mass 16% lower than that of calcium carbonate making baking soda _naively_ 16% more effective by mass, but the "all else being equal" assumption is what I'm really trying to correct with this question. Neither reaction will proceed 100% to completion, so I'm trying to figure out which does a better job with the HCl

Comment: The completeness of the reaction will depend on the limiting reactants. If HCl is in excess, the reaction will proceed to completion. However if you don't have enough, a buffer system will be formed. First of all, fix the amounts of baking soda and calcium carbonate. It is up to you. How many Tums are recommended in a single dose. What is their mass? Find the concentration of HCl in stomach acid and also find how many moles of HCl you are supposed to neutralize.

Comment: @M.Farooq How is this math done? What numbers am I looking for and how are they used? Also, this is starting to sound a lot like an answer :)

Comment: Did you search the equation I mentioned above?

Comment: @M.Farooq Ah that's great. So all you need is the dissociation constant and the ratio of acid to conjugate base concentration?